# Twill has correct form number but failed

Tags: python, browser, twill

I have this code to access the router's config.

```
class Peplink_login(threading.Thread):
    twill_browser = twill.browser.TwillBrowser()
    def login_sso(self):
        login_url = "http://" + ROUTER_IP + "cgi-bin/MANGA/index.cgi"
        st = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        print st+"url ---- %s" % login_url

        self.twill_browser.go(login_url)
        self.formvalue(self.twill_browser, "1", "username", "admin")
        self.formvalue(self.twill_browser, "2", "password", "admin")
        self.twill_browser.submit()
        sleep
        self.twill_browser.code(200)
        print "Login successful"
```

I am new to python and I need this to be sorted out. The error says "no matching forms" but I only have 2 input boxes on the main page. Why is that?

FYR:
[image]

Comment: I don't think there's enough information in this without seeing the code for your login_url website.

Comment: the router_ip = 192.168.50.1

Comment: Have you tried mechanize or mechanicalsoup instead?

Comment: sorry but I don't know much about python. I was given a python script and I need to record some data using it. But I am stuck on the first page where to put username and password.

Comment: Isnt this "self.formvalue" have to be "self.formvalue.formvalue("1", "username", "admin")" ?

Comment: it returns me this error formvalue() takes exactly 5 arguments

Comment: Have you found any solution ?